# Poco::File .remove(bool recursive = false); should have option .remove(bool recursive = false, bool preservetopdir);

Tags: poco-libraries

A POCO request.  I have a situation where a directory cannot be deleted (access rights), but the content is mine.  I can call Poco::File .remove(true) on this directory which does indeed delete all the content of the directory, but the call always throws an exception as the dir itself cannot be deleted.  So I have to frustratingly parse through the directory and remove each item individually.  A simple "preserve the top level directory" parameter would make my day.
If anyone hears this and agrees, thanks!!

Comment: Try GitHub issues: https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a feature request, which belongs to the repository issues list.